WiFi Advanced Settings replacement command for airport
Previously you could use the the airport prefs command to edit things like RequireAdminNetworkChange and RequireAdminPowerToggle (WiFi > Advanced > Require administrator authorisation to change betwork & turn WiFi on and off)
With macOS 14 this command is now deprecated and doesn't do anything. What is the "new" way to set these settings (Either by script/command or by configuration profile)
